# A curve in contravariant coordinate notation

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, geodesics, covariance

I'm reading a general relativity text, the metric is expected to describe generally the spacetime in a gravitational field. In it there is for ex. the notation
$$\sum_j g_{ij} \frac{dx^j}{ds}$$
for the case of a Riemann manifold and for some curve with parameter $s$ in it. Curves come up when one deals with geodesics, etc.

I feel confident that in Cartesian coordinates I can write this as
$$g_{i1}\frac{dx}{ds}+g_{i2}\frac{dy}{ds}+g_{i3}\frac{dz}{ds}+...$$
because the Cartesian coordinates, being orthogonal, would obey
$$x^j = x_j$$
that is, no difference between covariant and contravariant notation.

Can I proceed analogously in curvilinear, cylindrical polar coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$? Can I write
$$g_{i1}\frac{dr}{ds}+g_{i2}\frac{d\theta}{ds}+g_{i3}\frac{dz}{ds}+...$$

Cylindrical coordinates are orthogonal, but need to be certain.

Comment: Is this a special relativity or general relativity text? I.e. are you working with a general metric tensor (as your notation would suggest) or the Minkowski metric $\eta_{ij}$? In case of a general metric, you must, in general, distinguish between co- and contravariant quantities in any coordinate system.
On another note, spatial coordinates in GR are "naturally contravariant". It would be perfectly natural to introduce a contravariant coordinate system $x^\mu$ and split it into its components $(t,x,y,z)$.

Comment: It is a general relativity text, the metric is expected to describe generally the spacetime in a gravitational field

Comment: Then you have to be a little careful thinking about Cartesian coordinates; you can find a set of locally Cartesian coordinates for any space-time point, but they won't be "globally Cartesian" due to the metric. However, it seems to me that your question maybe relates more to notation? An expression like $x^\mu$ is just short-hand for $(t,x,y,z)$ or $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$ or some other coordinates, so you can always expand $g_{ij} x^{j}$ in the way that you write. Note, though, that you should make sure that the metric is expressed in the same basis.